# Lost messages in spark-streaming with checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Read from Kafka with Spark-Streaming and Checkpoint, but lost messages.

Code for generating a test stream:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import time

p = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='kafka.dev:9092')
for i in range(1000):
    time.sleep(2)
    p.send('y_test', value='{"test": ' + str(i) + '}')
```

Code for reading from kafka:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

def createContext():
    sc = SparkContext(appName='test_app')
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)
    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum='kafka.dev:2181',
            groupId='test_app', topics={'y_test': 1})
    kafkaStream.saveAsTextFiles('test_dir/')
    ssc.checkpoint('checkpoint_dir')
    return ssc

context = StreamingContext.getOrCreate('checkpoint_dir', createContext)
context.start()
context.awaitTermination()
```

How I check:

1) start code for reading

2) start code for generating

3) restart code for reading

4) read hdfs and see data failure:

```
{"test": 1}
{"test": 2}
{"test": 3}
{"test": 4}
{"test": 8}
{"test": 9}
{"test": 10}
{"test": 11}
{"test": 12}
```

Kafka 0.9.0.0, Spark 1.6.0

Comment: Please put info about your kafka configs

Comment: How do you restart? CTRL + C or Kill -9?

Comment: Also, did you verify the job was really started from checkpoint?